# Variable value not kept in while loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm facing a weird issue and I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong... There must be something!

I'll explain it shortly...
I'm developing for the Arduino platform (As far as I know it's heavily based on C++) and in a section of my actual code I have a while loop...

**So where's the issue?**

If I set a variable (a flag in my case) inside the while loop it gets resetted every time, this code is in a function... (may be useful)

Here it is:

```
void waitResponse(char* text) {
    static bool flag = false;
    count = 0;
    digitalWrite(GREEN_PIN, HIGH); //Turn OFF Green LED
    while (!espSerial.available()) { //Wait until we get some data in...
        Serial.println("No data");
        notBlockingBlink();
    } 
    while (!flag) { //We got sth
        Serial.print("Flag value 1: ");
        Serial.println(flag);
        while (espSerial.available()) {
            Serial.println("In");
            if (search(text)) {
                flag = true;
                Serial.println("Found");
                Serial.print("Flag value 2: ");
                Serial.println(flag);
                break;
            } else {
                notBlockingBlink();
            }
        }
        Serial.print("Flag value 3: ");
        Serial.println(flag);
        notBlockingBlink();
    }
}
```

I've tried to debug my issue...

After entering the if block where there is "**Found**", flag gets set to *true*, indeed "**Flag value 2:**" is *true* just like "**Flag value 3:**", but
at the next iteration "**Flag value 1:**" is actually *false*...

What's wrong? Please enlighten me! Thanks

Comment: _"I've tried to debug my issue..."_ Obviously not seriously enough.

Comment: What does `notBlockingBlink();` do?

Comment: @NathanOliver It makes an LED blink, but I guess It's irrelevant...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? I can't find the error I made...Help?

Comment: Since the outer `while` statement's condition is `!flag` (`while (!flag)`, it is impossible for `flag` to be true at the next statement. So the "next iteration" must be later, after `flag` has somehow gotten changed. (Although I don't know how that happens, since `flag` is static and local to the function.)

Comment: Looks like your waitResponse is being called many times and that is where the flag is set to `false`.  When the flag is set to `true`, your function exits.

Comment: @ingamedeo Well, step through your code line by line, and keep watching state values changing.

Comment: Debugging may be difficult since this is an embedded system.  Print statements may prove easier if the OP doesn't have a JTAG debugger or remote debugging capabilities.

Comment: @rici as far as I know !flag is only supposed to check if the opposite of the value of flag is true, is it wrong? Does it actually invert the value?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The code runs only one time... That's for sure ;)

Comment: @ingamedeo: No, it doesn't change the value. So if `flag` is true, the loop does not execute. Consequently, if the loop (and thus the `Serial.print` call) executes, `flag` *must be false*.

Comment: @rici Indeed! But I set it to true... So it should exit

Comment: @ingamedeo: yes, so there are two possibilities. (1) NotBlockingBlink corrupts memory. (2) The function is called a second time, after something else corrupted memory.

Comment: @rici You have been very helpful, thanks a lot really, I'll look into that code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your condition for the `while` loop is `!flag`, logically there is no possibility of having an iteration where `flag` is true. Therefore the behavior you believe *should* happen can *not* happen.

Comment: Okay... I thought so and so and I got really confused when it did... The variable seems to be resetting itself

Comment: Your function is called a second time. The variable is in fact local to the function, so it's not reset, it's just declared a second time (and initialised false).

Comment: I believe it should exit the loop... But it doesn't...That's the issue

Comment: @rainbowgoblin: Except that it's declared `static`.

Comment: You might want to update your question with what the problem actually was... Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is completely right, the fact that it's static means that some line OTHER THAN THE DECLARATION must be making the value of `flag` false.